# How to align LinearLayout at the center of its parent?

Tags: android-layout, android

I've looked through numerous similar questions here at SO, but nothing helps.
I have a hierarchy of different nested layouts, all have `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`, and the inner-most layout has `android:layout_width="wrap_content` - I need to align it at the center (horizontally). How do I do that?

**Update:**: I've found the cause of the problem - if I put the inner LinearLayout into RelativeLayout with `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`, it still wraps it's content. The TableRow, however, is really filling the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TableRow >
            <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                     <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
             </LinearLayout>
           </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 243, accepted):

These two attributes are commonly confused:

- `android:gravity` sets the gravity of the content of the View it's
  used on.
- `android:layout_gravity` sets the gravity of the View or
  Layout *relative to its parent*.

So either put `android:gravity="center"` on the parent or `android:layout_gravity="center"` on the LinearLayout itself.

I have caught myself a number of times mixing them up and wondering why things weren't centering properly...

Comment: I've tried `android:layout_gravity="center"` for the layout that contains the TextViews - doesn't help, it's still aligned left. Also tried to set this layout's width to `wrap` and `fill` - no difference.

Comment: Have you tried using the Pixel Perfect tool in Eclipse?  It shows you the borders on the layouts on a live version of your app, so you can generally figure out where you have gone wrong.

Comment: +1 for explaining the confusing difference between the element's and the parent's use of the keyword "gravity".

Comment: +1 coz it resolve my problem. My example = > I have a linear layout, and a textview in it. It works for texview. It centers the tw horizontally.

Comment: No layout_gravity for LinearLayout

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, to set center a textview in linear layout, use both. User android:gravity="center" on parent and android:layout_gravity="center" on the textview.

Comment: aptly named "layout"_gravity

Answer (score 14):

Please try this in your linear layout

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Comment: these parameters are for RelativeLayout

Comment: These aren't Linear Layout params

Comment: Cannot use this in linear layout.

Answer (score 11):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:text="1"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

           <TextView
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:text="2"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

consider wrapping relativeLayout over LinearLayout. `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` will position the view center horizontal.

Comment: Already tried that. It doesn't work! I don't understand what's going on there... I've posted the full code of my XML, I have only trimmed some other table rows. What's wrong with my layout?

Comment: it has something to do with table rows i think, they add the children to the left. consider giving layout_width = "fill_parent" for table row tag.

Comment: for the xml setup in this answer, if still having problems check again the `LinearLayout`'s `layout_width` which should be `wrap_content` and not `match_parent`. Same logic applies for aligning vertically

Answer (score 5):

add `layout_gravity="center"` or `"center_horizontal"` to the parent layout.

On a side note, your `LinearLayout` inside your `TableRow` seems un-necessary, as a `TableRow` is already an horizontal `LinearLayout`.

Comment: It is neccessary, because I need the table to fill the parent and only several rows to be centered. And layout_gravity doesn't help.

Answer (score 5):

If your parent is a LinearLayout, you can add to it :

```
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
```

And to it's child

```
android:gravity="center"
```

It should at least center horizontally !

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.. adding empty view ..

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >
<View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />  
     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

         android:id="@+id/adView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" >

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />  
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TableRow >
            <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >
                    <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                     <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
             </LinearLayout>
           </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me.

```
<LinearLayout>
.
.
.
android:gravity="center"
.
.>

<TextView
android:layout_gravity = "center"
/>
<Button
android:layout_gravity="center"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

so you're designing the Linear Layout to place all its contents(TextView and Button) in its center and then the TextView and Button are placed relative to the center of the Linear Layout

Answer (score 2):

Try `<TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal">` This will center the inner LinearLayout within the tablerow.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same situation while designing custom notification. I have tried with the following attribute set with true.

```
 android:layout_centerInParent.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Answer (score 1):

@jksschneider explation is almost right. Make sure that you haven't set any `gravity` to parent layout, and then set `layout_gravity="center"` to your view or layout.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this while working with nested RelativeLayouts.  My solution ended up being simple, but it's a little gotcha that's worth being aware of.

My layout was defined with...

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/someLayout
android:gravity="center"
```

...however, I didn't think that the layout below this one was placed on top of it.  Everything inside this layout was shifted towards the bottom instead of centered.  Adding...

```
android:layout_above="@id/bottomLayout"
```

...fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

for ImageView or others views who layout-gravity or gravity does not exist use :
            `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in the child 
(I had a relative layout with an ImageView as a child).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the **root's** (the main layout you store the other elements) gravity is not set. If you change it to **center** the other elements' gravity must work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Below is code to put your Linearlayout at bottom and put its content at center. You have to use RelativeLayout to set Layout at bottom.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#97611F"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="View Saved Searches"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:text="12"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />
  </LinearLayout>  
</RelativeLayout>
```