# Why is not center this layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my layout that is an action bar that I have built:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/Layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_blue_no_border">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="@drawable/white"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textActionBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Unfortunely the image is on the left and the textview is near the image.
I want that the second linear Layout is centered in the first layout. What have I to do?

Comment: use gravity insted of layout_centerHorizontal

Comment: Do you want to center the text and let the image remain on the left? Or center them both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/Layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_blue_no_border">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="@drawable/white"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textActionBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Or take a look here [How to align LinearLayout at the center of its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180887/how-to-align-linearlayout-at-the-center-of-its-parent)

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` works only for RelativeLayouts.

You could try making the parent layout as a RelativeLayout.

Or, add `layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` as an attribute for the child layout.

Or, add `gravity="center_horizontal"` as an attribute for the parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_centerHorizontal` works only within RelativeLayout.
In LinearLayout you should use `gravity`

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

to your parent layout and you are golden... or diamond. whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Assign `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` in your Child layout and also assign imageView and textView `android:layout_weight="1"` property for divide equal parts of space in your child layout.

Try this code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/Layout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textActionBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Hello"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
```

In TextView this line  `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` defines that textView is also center of an image height. So its upto you ,in your application this stuff is need or not.