# Android - cannot center button in fragment under viewpager

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

Quick question. I hope

I have this content-main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/pozadie" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="113dp" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

and this fragment of viewPager

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/pozadie" >


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="153dp" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Why cannot I center the button in fragment? It is still touching left or right border. In android studio, it is shown well. But not, when tried on phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

It was my fault. I forgot to change parent layout of main activity. It was set on static pixels of width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried gravity or layoutGravity?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8180931/6079360

Comment: Is it happening for all android versions? did you try in an emulator with same API?

Comment: Now, after you wrote it I tried gravity and layoutGravity, but it did not help, too. App was also tested on emulator with same api and button is shown badly there, too. Testing device is Lenovo.