# Centering inside of a LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout

How can I center three items inside of a LinearLayout? I tried several things but they are all placed to the left

```
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">



            <Button
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:drawableBottom="@drawable/arrow_white_down"
                android:theme="@style/PasswordButton" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TempNumb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:text="8°C"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:drawableBottom="@drawable/arrow_white_up"
                android:theme="@style/PasswordButton" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Turns out it all looks like this:
[image]

I want it all to be placed at the center. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180887/how-to-align-linearlayout-at-the-center-of-its-parent) answers your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `android:gravity="center"` to your LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this in your LinearLayout

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```

this is my output

[image]